# Haskell code using a pre definite variable

Tags: haskell

Could anybody tell me why the following code in Haskell is not working?

```
a = 5
foo :: Int -> Int -> Int
foo a 0 = 0
foo a b = a + foo a (b - 1)
  where
    a = a + 1
```

Comment: It doesn't work because the `a` in `a+1` refers to the `a` defined on that same line, so the definition is infinitely recursive. But which `a` do you want it to refer to? The parameter of `foo` or the one defined on line 1? Why do you have so many variables named `a`? What is the code meant to do? Is it just an experiment on how scope works?

Comment: It's just an experiment. I have a more complex problem and I reduced it at this simple. It's about adding 2 binary numbers using 2 functions: one for the actual sum and one for carry bit. I don't know how to transfer the value of the carry bit to the next step of the recursion

Comment: Okay, so how do you *want* the scope to work out. Like, what's your desired result here - which `a` do you want to refer to which definition? Do you want it to be the same as `foo a b = (a + 1) + foo (a + 1) (b - 1)` or something else?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want the function to do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Haskell a variable is in scope during its definition, so in `a = a + 1`, the `a` is referring to itself. If we rename the variables in your code, so that all variables have unique names, it will look like this:

```
a1 = 5
foo :: Int -> Int -> Int
foo _ 0 = 0
foo a2 b = a3 + foo a3 (b - 1)
  where
    a3 = a3 + 1
```

So the problem here is that `a3 = a3 + 1` is infinitely recursive - `a3` can't be equal to its own value plus one. Also `a2` is never used.

You said that you wanted it to refer to the value of the parameter, so now that the variables have different names we can fix this easily enough:

```
foo :: Int -> Int -> Int
foo _ 0 = 0
foo a2 b = a3 + foo a3 (b - 1)
  where
    a3 = a2 + 1
```

Note that I've left out `a1` this time since it's irrelevant to the `foo` function. We can also get rid of the `where` and just inline the `a2 + 1` part (and rename `a2` back to `a` since there will no longer be multiple ones):

```
foo :: Int -> Int -> Int
foo _ 0 = 0
foo a b = (a + 1) + foo (a + 1) (b - 1)
```